# How to get triplets from an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, torch

I have [1,2,3] and I wish to get [(1,1,1), (1,4,9), (1, 8, 27)]. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried and what were your results? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing your attempts in code so that we can offer specific help

Comment: Should your first numbers be `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: You said you're using numpy, so do you want a 2d numpy array as result or a list of tuples as you have in your question?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do this with a list comprehension, an inner loop iterating over your array/list, i. e. `[1,2,3]` and an outer loop iterating over the powers , i. e. zero, one and two (EDIT: To achieve the output you specified in your question one would need `[0,2,3]` as powers list):

```py
elements = [1,2,3]
powers = [0,1,2]
[[e**i for e in elements] for i in powers]
```

The output of this is

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]]
```

If you want a numpy array you can convert it with `np.array()` and if you want a list of tuples as you have it written in your question convert it with `tuple()`, i. e.

```py
import numpy as np
elements = [1,2,3]
powers = [0,1,2]

# numpy array
np.array([[e**i for e in elements] for i in powers])

# list of tuples
[tuple([e**i for e in elements]) for i in powers]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it this way, check it out:

```
def get_cuadrado_cubo(lista):
    resp = []
    for i in range (4):
        if i == 1:
            continue
        resp.append((lista [0] ** i, lista [1] ** i, lista [2] ** i) )

    return resp
```